# How to solve ArchTest violation of Config Layer accessed from Service Layer

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

My project violates a given structure test. I don't understand why the "config" layer must not be accessed by any other. Of course, I could use `@Value` annotation to directly access some K,V from a kind of `application.properties` file, but it feels like jumping from the frying pan into the fire. Additionally the project I do, has already a lot of `@Configuration` files clustered in the "config" package and all of them use different `*.YML` files, so I want to stick to this pattern.

How can I solve the violation problem and access configuration properties nonetheless from another layer that holds a service class and requires configuration data from the conf layer?

As an illustration I'll put my cut and relevant code here, beginning with the TEST:

```java
@AnalyzeClasses(packagesOf = MySecretApp.class, importOptions = DoNotIncludeTests.class)
class TechnicalStructureTest {

    // prettier-ignore
    @ArchTest
    static final ArchRule respectsTechnicalArchitectureLayers = layeredArchitecture()
        .layer("Config").definedBy("..config..")
        .layer("Web").definedBy("..web..")
        .optionalLayer("Service").definedBy("..service..")
        .layer("Security").definedBy("..security..")
        .layer("Persistence").definedBy("..repository..")
        .layer("Domain").definedBy("..domain..")

        .whereLayer("Config").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer()
        .whereLayer("Web").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Config")
        .whereLayer("Service").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Web", "Config")
        .whereLayer("Security").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Config", "Service", "Web")
        .whereLayer("Persistence").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Service", "Security", "Web", "Config")
        .whereLayer("Domain").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Persistence", "Service", "Security", "Web", "Config")

        .ignoreDependency(belongToAnyOf(MySecretApp.class), alwaysTrue())
        .ignoreDependency(alwaysTrue(), belongToAnyOf(

            dev.spectre.dominance.config.Constants.class,
            dev.spectre.dominance.config.ApplicationProperties.class
        ));
}
```

When I run the IT, I receive ERRORs of which I will give an example here:

```java
Constructor <dev.spectre.dominance.service.PrintService.<init>(dev.spectre.dominance.config.PrintServiceProperties)> has parameter of type <dev.spectre.dominance.PrintServiceProperties> in (PrintService.java:0)
```

The SERVICE class which violates the architecture rule has this structure:

```java
@Service
public class PrintService {

    private final PrintServiceProperties printServiceProperties;

    public PrintService(PrintServiceProperties printServiceProperties) {
        this.printServiceProperties = printServiceProperties;
    }

    @Async
    public void sendPrintjob(PrintJob job) {
        log.debug("Will send print job to Kafka with content: {} ", job.toString());
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.postForEntity(printServiceProperties.getUrl(), job, PrintJobAnswer.class);
    }
}
```

The CONFIGURATION class has this structure:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.printer")
public class PrintServiceProperties {

    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where does this ArchUnit test comes from? IMO the configuration should be accessible by any class

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it was auto-created by the jhipster generator. That's a kind of framework to enable developers to get a spring-backend and a e.g. node UI frontend as starter. I also believe, but cannot verify that configs should be accessed by all packages. Now I kept it as it was given to me and try to solve the issue. U think I should simply remove the rule? Can you give me ur thought?

Comment: Yes don't believe JHIpster. It's just an opinionated tool

Comment: You should open an issue on JHipster's github project and discuss with authors. You should not be forced to create a Configuration class to instantiate a service.